# "Issue with updating a record using a button”

Tags: php, mysql

When I click on the update button, the SQL query updates the last record not the wanted one

when displaying several courses, I would like to give the user the right to confirm one of the courses, when I click on the update button, it updates the last record

```
<?php
$cc = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from course WHERE c_email ='$emailu' AND course_situation='pending'");
while($ccc = mysqli_fetch_array($cc)) {
    $idcourse = $ccc['idcourse'];
    $city = $ccc['idville'];
    $pickup = $ccc['course_depart'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $idcourse ?></td>
        <td><?= $pickup ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ccc['course_date'] ?>, <?php echo
            $ccc['course_heure'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php
            if($ccc['course_situation'] == "pending") { ?>
                <span class="badge badge-danger">Pending</span>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <span class="badge badge-success">Confirmed</span>
            <?php } ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $ccc['c_phone'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ccc['c_phone'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ccc['idclient'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" name="cancelcourse" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="icon md-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update</button>
    </tr>
<?php }

if(isset($_POST["cancelcourse"])) {
    $query = "UPDATE course SET id='$idu' AND course_situation='confirmed' WHERE idcourse='$idcourse' ";

    if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
        echo "<div class='  alert alert-success' style='padding-left:150px'>
<strong>Success!</strong> Event page updated.</a>.
</div>";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">';
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
<strong>ERROR!</strong> We invite you to try Again Later.
</div> " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not even seeing a form here.

Comment: The UPDATE syntax is incorrect.

Comment: You're not getting any values from a supposed form (that doesn't exist). You're iterating through the values to output the table, then you run an update query with the values that you used in your loop, so those variables are set to the values from the last row in your table. Rethink your design here.

Comment: What do you propose to do  ?

Comment: Honestly, it would probably be good for you to go back to the basics and review some guides/tutorials on HTML forms and how to handle them with PHP and safely save the data into a database.

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

You generate button for each course, but all your buttons are equal, they don't contains any information about which course you want to update. You use variable `$idcourse`, but it is assigned inside while-loop that generates table - for each row that is shown this variable is changed, so after showing whole table it will contains id for last row.

Please remember, that each time your page is reloaded (like after clicking button) whole script is executed from beginning and no variables are stored, unless you pass it yourself.

Simplest solution:

1.Add id to button

```
<button type="submit" name="cancelcourse" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($idcourse)?>">
```

2.Change query

```
$idcourseToRemove = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["cancelcourse"]);
$query = "UPDATE course SET id='$idu' AND course_situation='confirmed' WHERE idcourse='$idcourseToRemove' ";
```

And last advice: learn about SQL Injection and how to avoid it (like for example by `mysqli_real_escape_string` function)

Answer (score -3):

> UPDATE course SET id='$idu',course_situation='confirmed' WHERE
>   idcourse='$idcourse'